# Issue with displaying related object fields in email alert via trigger using Email Template

Tags: trigger, email-alert, visualforce-template

I am sending an email alert from my trigger using the below template. The problem is that {!relatedTo.Id} cant be seen in the email alert. How could this be achieved other than substituting the email template by hard-coding the html body in the trigger?

The following opportunity stage has been changed

{!relatedTo.Id}

Thank you!

Comment: Are you setting a TargetObjectId for the email message?

Comment: Hi Martin,Here goes the email template code. I cant see the relateTo id which in this case is the opportunity id in the email alert(fired via a trigger)


<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Opportunity stage change" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <html>
        <body>
            <p>The following opportunity stage has been changed</p>
            <p>{!relatedTo.Id}</p>
            <p>Thank you!</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>11

Comment: Martin , Yes i am setting a user as TargerObjectId.

Comment: I think I meant to ask about the WhatId. The `TargetObjectId` refers to the `recipient`, the `WhatId` refers to the `relatedTo`.

Comment: I did not use set the WhatId. However I just set the WhatId and it is working now. Thank you! Martin